# Not bootable Ubuntu 16 LTS after install along with windows 8.1 64 bit OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

After install Ubuntu 16 LTS along with windows 8.1 64 bit OS.Its not bootable.
I have install different partition but its shows ubuntu install successfully.When i start the computer only windows 8.1 fetch by bootable manager.Secure boot disable and UEFI mode selected.

Comment: Looks like your `fast boot` option in Windows is still enabled. Disable it and then perform the steps as given here. 1) Boot into `Windows` OS. 2) Combine `Windows` + `r` key together and type `cmd` to open command prompt. 3) Once you are in command prompt window, type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit `Enter` key. 
As soon as you execute this command and reboot your system, you will be able to see both options of `Windows` and `Ubuntu` on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the `Fast Boot` option in Windows 8.1 is probably still enabled (which would just make your computer boot into Windows 8.1).

Do you get to the GRUB menu where you can select which OS to start, or are you using something else as a boot manager?

If disabling the `Fast Boot` option doesn't help, could you boot up Ubuntu from a USB stick and check with `gparted` if you have the correct partitions?